# can't install mysql 5.6 on fedora 27 via rpm

Tags: mysql, repository, rpm, fedora-27

Am trying to install mysql 5.6 on fedora 27. I need 5.6 or 5.5 specifically to run openmrs. I've followed the tutorial at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html. However, for some reason after adding the yum repository i cannot select the 5.6 release. I can disable the 5.7 release with;

```
sudo dnf-config-manager --disable mysql57-community
```

I can't enable the 5.6 release with;

```
sudo dnf-config-manager --enable mysql56-community
```

The package is just not provided after adding the repository. Wondering if anyone has succeeded or if there is another way. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask this question on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Are you sure that package exists? Fedora tends to burn off all the underbrush on a regular basis and works to stay current.

Comment: The MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html claims it exists. Probably a flaw in the documentation. Am not sure it exists.